# How to make particular cell visible inside Gridview, not complete column?

Tags: c#, winforms

I had a Gridview which contains 3 columns , initially during form load i only two columns will be visible one column will be having data and other having checkbox.

i want when i check a checkbox in particular cell, corresponding to that checkbox the third column cell will be visible, i don't want to complete 3rd column to get visible on checking a check box ,Gridview is hardcoded only rows are dymanic (column1,column2 are set to visible  and column 3 is set to invisible)

in below inmage when i m checking checkbox complete thried column is visible,which i don't want
[image]

[image]

can any one help me in this?

i tried below code but it is making 3rd column visible not, particular cell

```
public form1() 
{
    dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
}

void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex + 1].Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: You want any checked cell in the second column will have the corresponding cell in the third column `visible`?

Comment: yes, i want the cell to be visible corresponding to the checkbox.... but clicking on one checkbox should not display complete column

Answer (score 0):

Well You can try RowCommand event for this but as i see you already have event created for checkbox ,Try to find row Index for particular row and then use Cell number (cell[2]) to find the control and assign its property as visible = false,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo I've just tried. It seems to work OK. The whole idea is **You can't hide a particular cell in DataGridView**. However you can make it hidden as a normal GUI engine will use when it wants to hide any control/element (I think so). You just customize it to paint the cell with the `BackgroundColor` of your `DataGridView`. Of course, to make it work, it's not such easy. Here is the code for you:

```
//First, you have to be sure the whole third column is Visible.
//CellPainting event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)//This is the Column index you want to hide.
        {                
            object o = e.RowIndex == -1 ? null : dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex - 1,e.RowIndex].Value;
            if (o!=null &&!(bool)o || e.RowIndex == -1 || e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.BackgroundColor), e.CellBounds);
                if(e.RowIndex > -1) dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = true;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if (o != null && (bool)o)
            {
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly = false;                    
            }
        }
    }
//CellContentClick event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   UpdateThirdColumCell(e);
}
//CellContentDoubleClick event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   UpdateThirdColumCell(e);
}
private void UpdateThirdColumCell(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)//The column index of the CheckBox column
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            cell.Value = cell.EditingCellFormattedValue;
            dataGridView1.Invalidate();
            if ((bool)cell.Value)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex + 1, e.RowIndex];
            }
        }
}
//CellStateChanged event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cell.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.Cell.Selected)
    {
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
    }
}
```

And that's all :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ,actually we can't make invisible but i want to give an explianation about it in simple way.using

```
datagridview.rows(e.rowindex).cells[your column name]=true ;
```

using this it won't allow the user to enter the data in the textbox.if it is false then we can modify it/enter any text.

```
datagridview.rows(e.rowindex).cells[your column name].backcolour=color.gray/white/black;
```

using this we can fill color to a particular textbox which is to be painted when checkbox is true/false;